# Gibberish in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I moved a report (rdl file) from a 2008 ssrs server to a new 2012 server.

The connections is to oracle and it works ok (although a little slow).
The issue is that some of the columns are in Hebrew which worked in the old server however in the new server I only get gibberish.
The number columns and the text boxes are fine even though the text boxes are in Hebrew as well.
Does anyone know of a way to get these columns to make sense (to Hebrew speakers at least)?

Thanks very much for all your help,

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the connection to an OLE DB connection for Oracle instead of an Oracle connection.
:) Thanks my own brain.